# Números correlativos según último registro insertado

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy creando y guardando en la base de datos un número correlativo al último guardado, en una consulta que se ejecuta dentro de un bucle.

La correlatividad está lograda y el primer registro lo inserta correctamente, pero los siguientes, en lugar de leer el último valor insertado, lee el anterior.

Es decir:

Si en la base de datos, el último registro es el 00003.

todos los registros que se insertan serán con el número 00004.

y lo que necesito es que se inserten 00004, 00005, 00006, 00007, etc.

Aquí mi código y espero haber sido claro.
Saludos y gracias!

```
<?php

    $Cliente=$_POST['cliente'];
    $ClientesAFacturar = array_unique($Cliente);

    $num=0;
    foreach ($ClientesAFacturar as $NuevaFactura)
    {
        $num++; 

        include ("includes/conexion.php");
        $resultClientes = mysql_query("SELECT id_cliente, razonsocial, nombrefantasia, direccion_fiscal,nro_fiscal,piso_fiscal,depto_fiscal,codigopostal_fiscal,localidad_fiscal,provincia_fiscal,pais_fiscal,cuit,id_iva,periodofacturacion,tipofacturacion,condicionpago,descuento,diasvencimiento,id_facturador
            FROM clientes
            WHERE id_cliente = '$NuevaFactura'
        ");

        if ($rowCliente= mysql_fetch_array($resultClientes)){ 
            $NumCliente=$rowCliente["id_cliente"];
            $Facturador=$rowCliente["id_facturador"];

            do { 
?>

...

<div class="col-md-8 mb5">
<?php
    $resultFacturador = mysql_query("SELECT id_facturador, facturadortalonario, facturadoriva FROM facturadores WHERE id_facturador = '$Facturador'"); 
    if ($rowFacturador = mysql_fetch_array($resultFacturador)){ 
        $FacturadorIVA = $rowFacturador["facturadoriva"];
        do { 
            $FacturadorTalonario = $rowFacturador["facturadortalonario"];
        }
        while ($rowFacturador = mysql_fetch_array($resultFacturador)); 
    } else { 
        echo 'No tiene facturador cargado.'; 
    }

    //Obtener último numero insertado en la DDBB y Genera nuevo Numero de Factura

    $rs = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(id_facturadeventa) AS idFactura, FacturadorTalonario FROM facturasdeventa WHERE FacturadorTalonario = '$FacturadorTalonario' ");
    if ($row = mysql_fetch_row($rs)) {
        $numfactura = trim($row[0]);
    }
    $rsped = mysql_query("SELECT id_facturadeventa, FacturadorTalonario, facturaNumero FROM facturasdeventa WHERE id_facturadeventa = '$numfactura' ");
    while ($rowrsped = mysql_fetch_array($rsped)) {
        $numero_factura_ultima=$rowrsped["facturaNumero"];
    }

    $numero_factura_nueva = $numero_factura_ultima;
    $numero_factura_nueva++;

?>

<h1>factura <b>A</b></h1><br>
<h4>N&ordm;: <?php 
    $NumeroDeFacturaNuevo = str_pad($numero_factura_nueva, 9, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); 
    $NumeroDeFacturaCompleto = $FacturadorTalonario . "-" .  $NumeroDeFacturaNuevo;
    echo ''.$NumeroDeFacturaCompleto.'';

?>
</h4>

...

    <input type="hidden" id="FacturadorTalonario" name="FacturadorTalonario" value="<?php echo ''.$FacturadorTalonario.'';?>">
    <input type="hidden" id="NumeroDeFacturaNuevo" name="NumeroDeFacturaNuevo" value="<?php echo ''.$NumeroDeFacturaNuevo.'';?>">
.........
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var FacturadorTalonario = $("#remitosfacturados<?php echo ''.$num.'';?> #FacturadorTalonario").val();
        var facturaNumero = $("#remitosfacturados<?php echo ''.$num.'';?> #NumeroDeFacturaNuevo").val();


        //Aquí llama a otro archivo que inserta los datos en la DDBB.


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "facturas_escribirfacturaenddbb.php",

            data: {FacturadorTalonario:FacturadorTalonario, facturaNumero:facturaNumero, FechaDeFactura:FechaDeFactura},

            beforeSend: function(){
                $("#ResultadoDeFactura<?php echo ''.$num.'';?>").html("<p align='center'><img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' /></p>");
            },
            error: function(data){
                $("#ResultadoDeFactura<?php echo ''.$num.'';?>").html("Error en la actualizaci&oacute;n de datos. Intente nuevamente.") 
            },
            success: function(data){        
                $("#ResultadoDeFactura<?php echo ''.$num.'';?>").html(data);
            }
        });

    });
</script>

<div class="form-title">
    <div class="form-two widget-shadow">

        <div id="Letras<?php echo ''.$num.'';?>"></div> 

    </div>

    <div id="ResultadoDeFactura<?php echo ''.$num.'';?>"></div>
</div> 
<?php 
            } while ($rowCliente = mysql_fetch_array($resultClientes)); 
        } else { 
            ECHO 'No existe el cliente.';
        }
    } //Fin foreach
?>
```

Archivo facturas_escribirfacturaenddbb.php

```html
<?php

$facturaNumero=$_POST['facturaNumero'];
$FacturadorTalonario=$_POST['FacturadorTalonario'];
$FechaDeFactura=$_POST['FechaDeFactura'];
$FechaDeVencimiento=$_POST['FechaDeVencimiento'];
$PeriodoImputacion=$_POST['PeriodoImputacion'];
$id_cliente=$_POST['id_cliente'];
$cuit=$_POST['cuit'];
$cuitLimpio = preg_replace('([^A-Za-z0-9])', '', $cuit);           
$iva_condicion=$_POST['iva_condicion'];
$subtotalparaBBDD=$_POST['subtotalparaBBDD'];
$descuento=$_POST['descuento'];
$iva_valor=$_POST['iva_valor'];
$total=$_POST['total'];


$connect = include ("includes/conexion.php");



//Escribe Factura en DDBB

if(isset($facturaNumero)){
 
$queryInsertaFactura = 
"INSERT INTO facturasdeventa (FacturadorTalonario,facturaNumero,FechaDeFactura,FechaDeVencimiento,PeriodoImputacion,id_cliente,cuit,iva_condicion,subtotal,descuento,iva_valor,total) VALUES ('$FacturadorTalonario', '$facturaNumero', '$FechaDeFactura', '$FechaDeVencimiento', '$PeriodoImputacion', '$id_cliente', '$cuitLimpio', '$iva_condicion', '$subtotalparaBBDD', '$descuento', '$iva_valor', '$total')";

if (mysql_query($queryInsertaFactura) === TRUE) {
    echo "Factura generada correctamente.";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $queryInsertaFactura . "<br>";
};

mysql_close($connect);
}

?>
```

Comment: podrias utilizar las funciones propias de mysql para obtener el id del ultimo registro insertado/actualizado y en base a ello hacer la consulta para obtener el numero correlativo , es un punto de vista

Comment: un ejemplo de insert: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_lastid.asp

Comment: Es una opción pero no resuelve mi problema. 
Lo que necesito es que el número se genere en PHP y se inserte, no el id automático.

Comment: Podrias aislar el codigo relevante a tu pregunta? El bloque que presentas contiene mucha informacion que genera ruido.

Comment: @cavpollo ya he sintetizado el código y agregado algunas aclaraciones en comentarios //.

Comment: Según veo en tu código tú obtienes el último id en esta variable: `$numfactura`... ¿es así?  Si lo es,  no veo ningún `INSERT` en el cual la uses ni la incrementes luego para que se sigan insertando valores con `...4, 5, 6, 7...` ¿o estoy enfocando mal el problema?

Comment: El INSERT está en el archivo "facturas_escribirfacturaenddbb.php" que llama desde AJAX.
Lo agrego al post para que se pueda ver.

Comment: Sigo sin entender la lógica. Te pregunto de nuevo: ¿el número que debería incrementarse en cada inserción es el de la variable `$numfactura`? ¿o cuál es?  Yo no veo que tú incrementes ese número en ninguna parte. Tampoco entiendo ¿por qué pasas del servidor a Ajax para una inserción???

Comment: @A.Cedano El número que se incrementa es el de la variable $numero_factura_nueva. Donde está definida también se define el incremento.
Paso variables por AJAX para poder insertar en la base de datos variables definidas en JQuery. (No sé hacerlo de otro modo).

Comment: Sigo sin entender... Yo no veo que en el `INSERT` tú uses la variable `$numero_factura_nueva` para nada... En cuanto a Ajax, tampoco entiendo ¿qué datos necesitas de jQuery, te refieres a datos que serán llenados en el navegador por el usuario? Creo que deberías dedicar un poquito de tiempo a la pregunta, editándola y explicando cómo tienes organizado el código y qué hace cada cosa. A mi me da que hay un error de planteamiento o de lógica en el código y por eso se te está dificultando algo que casi seguro es relativamente fácil.